# How to increase the performance of gae query?

Tags: python, performance, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have implemented a logic of querying  a table and for each entity in that particular table, I have to lookup another table.

For, ex.

My code looks like,

```
query = ndb.gql("select * from Foo where user = :1", user.key)
stories, next_cursor, more = query.fetch_page(size, start_cursor=cursor)
if next_cursor:
   for story in stories:
       print story.key
       images = ndb.gql("select * from Images where story = :1", story.key)
       for image in images:
           print image.key
else:
   #do some operations
```

You see, if we give the size as 10 to the fetch_page function, it would find 10 entities each. And for each entity, we have to lookup another kind `Image`.

This type of datastore lookup takes 850 to 950 ms. I want to decrease the response time of this API. 
Note that I have to get some column values from `Story` kind and also from `Images` kind.

Is there anyway to shorten the query by using `get_multi` method. Or, I have an idea of using `memcache` or shall we define a new `StructuredProperty` in the `Foo` model where it's value must be a list of `Images` model entities.

I donno which one suits in this case.. Pls guide me.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a property to each Story that contains a list of Image ids. I assume that this list rarely changes. Then you can easily `get_multi` all images related to a story without any queries.

You may also consider to `get_multi` all images for all stories, returned by your query, in a single call, and then "attach" them to respective stories in your code, if necessary.

Comment: you mean defining like `images = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Image, repeated=True)` inside story model?

Comment: Yes. You can use keys, if you prefer. I often use ids instead of full keys because they take less space, and you can always create a full key from id. But this may be unnecessary over-optimization if your dataset is not huge. And I come from the Java side, so I don't know if this is already optimized in Python.

Comment: like this `ndb.key('class_name', id).get()` to get an entity by id or `cls.get_by_id(id)`

Comment: Yes, but you should always go for `get_multi` whenever possible. It makes a big difference.

Comment: how to create an id? I know id, we are passing to create an entity is a string. How do I generate an unique id?

Comment: oh, we have to story the ids in  a list after the image entity creation, right? we can easily get the id by, `Image.key.id()`

Comment: if we do like so, then `get_multi` would work on list of id's? I know it would work on list of keys..

Comment: You will have to create a list of keys from a list of ids. It's a simple loop. But as I said before, this may be an unnecessary over-optimization. You are saving a few hundred bytes per key at most.

Comment: If I store a list of id's instead of keys, I got this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39405891/how-to-increase-the-performance-of-gae-query#comment66145929_39406179 problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whole structure of your project, but...

You can do something like that:

```
class Story(ndb.Model):
    images = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Image, repeated=True)
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
```

and every time user will add new image update it (`images` property of `Story`).

Then you'll be able to use:

```
images = []
stories = Story.query.filter(Story.user == user.key)
stories = stories.fetch(size)
for story in stories:
    images.extend(ndb.get_multi(story.images))
print images
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: why a separate model for index. Why don't we define `images = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Image, repeated=True)` inside the `Story` kind?

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Of course you can do that. I just didn't know all dependencies.

Comment: I have one doubt.. How to build a key using enity id? `Key('User', 'root', 'User', 5629499534213120, 'LifeStory', 6333186975989760, 'LifestoryImagesMapping', 4925812092436480)` I want the entity which has the above key to be returned. But I can be able to create a partial key `Key('LifestoryImagesMapping', '4925812092436480')`

Comment: On applying `get()` on the partial key, I get `None` . I know `LifestoryImagesMapping` entity is created using `Lifestory` model's entity key as parent.

Comment: Well, you can create ``CustomIndex`` class where you'll put all those keys as fields and when creating Index instance, just concatenate ids: ``'{}-{}-{}'.format(5629499534213120, 6333186975989760, 4925812092436480'`` put it as ``id`` and then you can get it by ``ndb.Key('CustomIndex', '{}-{}-{}'.format(5629499534213120, 6333186975989760, 4925812092436480)).get()``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122991/discussion-between-avinash-raj-and-turkus).

Comment: seems like a bit overkill for me. Why don't we convert the keys to urlsafe string and then store those strings inside ListProperty? We may easily build keys from urlsafe strings.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look at NDB batch async API

```
   @ndb.tasklet
   def get_stories(user_key):
     stories = yield Story.query(Story.user_key == user_key).fetch_async()
     futs = [
       item.key.get_async() for item in stories]
     result = yield futs
     raise ndb.Return(result)

   get_stories(user_key).get_result()
```

This API will only call 2 queries.

1. make a query to DataStore
2. with N result from the above query, make 1 query to get all stories

Since, `Key.get_async()` also use memcache automatically, from the seconds time you call above function, the 2 query will call to memcache